# AWS elastic search error "[Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known."

Tags: python, aws-elasticsearch

I created one AWS elasticsearch instance. I want to access it using a python script. I specified my AWS configuration (access key, secret key, region). I am using below code to access the AWS ES instance:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, RequestsHttpConnection
from requests_aws4auth import AWS4Auth

AWS_ACCESS_KEY = '**************'
AWS_SECRET_KEY = '*****************'
region = 'us-east-1'
service = 'es'

awsauth = AWS4Auth(AWS_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SECRET_KEY, region, service)

host = 'https://kbckjsdkcdn.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com' # For example, my-test-domain.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com

es = Elasticsearch(
    hosts = [{'host': host, 'port': 443}],
    http_auth = awsauth,
    use_ssl = True,
    verify_certs = True,
    connection_class = RequestsHttpConnection
)

print es.info()
```

When I am running the above code, I am getting following error:

```
elasticsearch.exceptions.ConnectionError:  ConnectionError(HTTPSConnectionPool(host='https', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: //search-opendata-2xd6pwilq5sv4ahomcuaiyxmqe.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com:443/ (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x10ee72310>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known',))) caused by: ConnectionError(HTTPSConnectionPool(host='https', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: //search-opendata-2xd6pwilq5sv4ahomcuaiyxmqe.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com:443/ (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x10ee72310>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known',)))
```

How can I resolve this error?

Thanks

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known` seems to indicate that the elasticsearch client is not able to resolve the hostname. It could possibly be because you include the protocol `https://` specified in the host.

Change that line to `host = 'kbckjsdkcdn.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com'` to see if it works. Also the example comment you have there, seems to indicate that the protocol should not be included in the host variable.

Comment: Great answer. Most examples on the web are incorrect. And it's so simple...