# how to resolve SnowSQL login issue

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I encountered this error when trying to connect to my Snowflake account by SnowSQL. Any suggestion what might be the issue and how to resolve it?

```
% snowsql -a https://*****.us-east-2.aws.snowflakecomputing.com/ -u *****
Password: 
250003 (n/a): Failed to execute request: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='https', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: //*****.us-east-2.aws.snowflakecomputing.com/.snowflakecomputing.com:443/session/v1/login-request?request_id=6585191e-6947-487e-acae-c2cfc777bd1c (Caused by NewConnectionError('<snowflake.connector.vendored.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f8dc80205f8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known',))
If the error message is unclear, enable logging using -o log_level=DEBUG and see the log to find out the cause. Contact support for further help.
```

Comment: Have you purposely removed your account name from the above log line? `https://.us-east-2.aws.snowflakecomputing.com/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try the below syntax:

snowsql -a [accountname].us-east-2.aws -u [username]

Details: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowsql-start.html#connection-syntax

Comment: "https://" and "snowflakecomputing.com" is not part of the -a. Also, if you can try it again and attach a screenshot

Comment: I tried 2 ways. got the same error for both:

Comment: Commands tried

snowsql -a ***.useast-2.aws.snowflakecomputing.com -u ***

snowsql -a ***.useast-2.aws -u ***

Error:
250003 (n/a): Failed to get the response. Hanging? method: post, url: https://***.useast-2.aws.snowflakecomputing.com:443/session/v1/login-request?request_id=59c5169c-5709-451c-9e38-1e4de8eb92b7&request_guid=e83a329b-2811-4647-8127-322c30bde7d8

Comment: Please remove snowflakecomputing.com

Comment: I opened a new terminal and tried this command again and it worked. thx!       snowsql -a ***.useast-2.aws -u ***

Comment: Great. can you please mark it as answered. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One thing I always try is to make sure I can login from the console/UI with the username and password - before I tackle snowsql connectivity issues.  You might have already tried, lmk.
Also, it appears you left off your account name from the URL... was that on purpose (for confidentiality) or a possible problem with URL?

Comment: thanks for the reply. Yes, I have tried and I'm able to login from UI with the same user name and password. I left the user name from the URL when posted the question here on purpose.

Comment: I'm using Mac laptop, python 3.9. Not sure whether it is related to the issue but want to share this info.

Comment: actually...  i was reading another post( https://stackoverflow.com/a/48276166/16318836) and it looks like dropping https:// will do the trick... lmk

Comment: Commands tried:

(1) snowsql -a ***.useast-2.aws.snowflakecomputing.com -u ***

(2) snowsql -a ***.useast-2.aws -u ***

Error:
250003 (n/a): Failed to get the response. Hanging? method: post, url: https://***.useast-2.aws.snowflakecomputing.com:443/session/v1/login-request?request_id=59c5169c-5709-451c-9e38-1e4de8eb92b7&request_guid=e83a329b-2811-4647-8127-322c30bde7d8

Comment: the issue was resolved by using this command. thx! snowsql -a ***.useast-2.aws -u ***

Comment: Which was suggested on Aug 10, above ;). All the best

Answer (score 0):

The correct account for use with the `snowsql` command appears to be *account*.*region*.*cloud provider*. For example: XXXXXXX.eu-west-2.aws.

The whole command with an example account and username:

```
snowsql -a ocXXXXX.eu-west-2.aws -u myusername
```